# passing parameters between methods of controller (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1

i have 2 controllers methods create and show

```
def create
   @message2 = Message.new(params[:message])
   if @message2.valid?
   @message2 = current_user.sent_messages.create(params[:message])         
      redirect_to @message2.receiver    
    else
      redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

and

```
def show

   @message = Message.find(params[:id])
   if current_user==@message.receiver
     @message.is_read=true
     @message.save
     @message2=Message.new(:receiver_id=>@message.sender, :sender_id=>current_user,:theme=>@message.theme)
   else
     @message2=Message.new(:receiver_id=>@message.receiver, :sender_id=>current_user,:theme=>@message.theme)
   end


end
```

my form

```
= form_for(@message2) do |f|

  %p
    Content:
    %br
    = f.text_area :content ,:rows => 5,:id => "text_area",
                :cols => 45

  .actions
    = f.submit
```

in show view i have form which initialize @message2.content but create action cleans all parameters which I set in show action and sets only content value. How to make my form to append parameters (not to clean old)?

Comment: please, help, very need to solve this problem

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do?  Can you post your views?.  Note: your show , by contract, should only show message, why are you updating and creating new message in the show?

Comment: cause i dont have params[:id] in create; i started to initialize @message2 in show method. and want to continue initializng in create. But i dont know how, i can create new only in create action. I am newbie, i know that there are are ways of doing this but i dont know what are they(

Comment: my form initialize :theme parameter, i want to add this parameter to existing variable , not creating new one with :there initialized only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
  @message2 = current_user.sent_messages.new(params[:message])         
  if @message2.save
    redirect_to @message2.receiver    
  else
    render :action => :show
  end
end
```

Here's how your `create` action should look. This is a commonly used Rails idiom.

It will render the form correctly, because the instance variable is still there.

Comment: hmm, will it have :receiver_id and :sender_id initialized? like i have initialized in my show action? cause in my case create action is performed after show action

Comment: You have to add `f.hidden_field :receiver_id` and `:sender_id` to the form.

Comment: thanks, it's like i made, but 1 man told me that it is not good way, is he right?. I always need to use hidden fields? for example if i will have 2 forms for 1 model( 1 form initialize 1 parameter , and second - second), i need to use hidden fields?

Comment: @Pavel, ok, I'm not sure how your objects are organized, but it seems that `sender==current_user`, so you don't have to specify `sender_id` in the form, but you still have to specify the `receiver_id`, unless you get it from your routes. In which case you'd have to merge it with `params[:message]` in `create`.